# Как в словаре изменить значения

Tags: python, словари

У нас есть словарь:

```
last_order = {
'DARUSDT': ['sell', 1, 5],
'CELRUSDT': ['sell', 0, 0],
'CTSIUSDT': ['sell', 0, 0],
}
```

у нас есть 2 списка:

```
a1 = [10]
b2 = [7]
```

как в словаре, в ключе 'DARUSDT' изменить значения [1] на значения из переменной a1, а в значения [5] на значения из переменной b2?

Comment: last_order['DARUSDT'][1] = 10 last_order['DARUSDT'][2] = 7

Comment: вам уже подсказали в комментарии. это азы python. может, вам учебник начать читать?

Answer (score 0):

```
last_order['DARUSDT'][1] = a1[0]
last_order['DARUSDT'][2] = b2[0]
```

Если ответ Вам помог, отметьте его